# Rails - no command prompt after starting server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

total n00b question here but I can't seem to find the answer searching around here or the web.

I have Ruby v1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) and Rails v.2.3.5 installed on my Mac (10.6.8). I have no problem generating a Rails directory and starting the Ruby server, but what happens is that once the server is started I have no prompt and no code I type seems to execute.

to be specific - here is the terminal code from a session:

```
bvb:new bennettvonbennett$ ruby script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```

after this point there is no prompt and no command I type seems to produce a result.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I should add that the localhost:3000 page loads just fine in a browser...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. You're not doing anything wrong.

The server runs in the foreground so that you can see the log output on every page load without having to open a specific log file. It's very helpful for debugging and staying aware of what the code you write does to the application and the database.

To return to a normal command prompt, you can send an end-of-text character (usually ctrl-c) to stop the server. Most of us Rails-folk work with multiple terminal windows open - server running in one, and others for other functions, such as the rails console, started with

```
ruby script/console
```

which will let you experiment with other Rails controller functions, much like irb for standard Ruby.

Comment: ahhh... I see! you would think that somewhere in the first few chapters of my 2 Rails books they would make that clear!
appreciate the help people...

Comment: Yup, the books are thick on syntax and thin on practice. Glad we could help.

Answer (score 3):

With `ruby script/server` you launch the webserver. Run `ruby script/console` if you want to execute commands against your current Rails application.

Answer (score 1):

You're loooking for:

```
script/console
```

If you want to play with your project in a console.